# Put a background image behind active link on nav bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking to create a nav menu where the active link has a background image behind it and as the next link is clicked the image goes to the next active link. I am not sure if this can be done solely with CSS or if some jQuery is required also.

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="company_name">

    </div>
        <ul id="gen_navigation" class="container_fixed">
            <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Technology</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Applications</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Benefits</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Inquiries</span></a></li>
        </ul>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dk6eq/

**Note:** I only have the basic css and html at the moment

Comment: It can not be done with CSS as it does not have a click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done with just CSS since CSS has no lasting "click" trigger.

Simply add a CSS class, something like

```
.active {
   background-image: url(...)
}
```

Then, when you click...

```
$("#gen_navigation a").on('click', function () {
   $("#gen_navigation a").removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: I added the class and that coding word for word..Im still not getting anything coming up

Comment: @Blake never do it word-for-word; what I have is just an example.  `url(...)` obviously won't work, you need the real path to your image.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/socialdtheway2be/Dk6eq/2/ I think the other link was broken..I included the image in that

Comment: @Blake you didn't change the framework to jQuery.  Also, that does not appear to link to an image

Comment: ah ok got it..simple coding error in dreamweaver with the script..thanks for you help